# How to detect the browser/device using javascript,css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, user-agent

I want to detect if the device is desktop or mobile or tablet .. On this basis i want to change the image directory 
for eg

```
if (getDeviceState() == 'phone') {
              alert("phone");
          }
          else if (getDeviceState() == 'tablet') {
              alert("tablet");
          }
          else {
              alert("small-desktop");
          }
```

i have tried this using css and javascript

```
          var indicator = document.createElement('div');
          indicator.className = 'state-indicator';
          document.body.appendChild(indicator);

          // Create a method which returns device state
          function getDeviceState() {
              var index = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(indicator).getPropertyValue('z-index'), 10);

              var states = {
                  2: 'small-desktop',
                  3: 'tablet',
                  4: 'phone'
              };

              return states[index] || 'desktop';
          }
          if (getDeviceState() == 'phone') {
              alert("phone");
          }
          else if (getDeviceState() == 'tablet') {
              alert("tablet");
          }
          else {
              alert("small-desktop");
          }
```

and in css

```
/* small desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .state-indicator {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

/* tablet */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .state-indicator {
        z-index: 3;
    }
}

/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 360px) {
    .state-indicator {
        z-index: 4;
    }
}
```

But i am getting prob for landscape and potrait states..so its better to get useragent than by css

Comment: I'm not the one to give you the perfect answer to your question. But what I do know is there are a large number of very nice frameworks, jQuery plugins and other ways available to do the detection. Why bother writing your own?
On your question: might be a idea to check how it's done in Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: try this:      http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: You can olso detect that using JS library like Modernizr

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `device.js` http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/

source code and examples can be obtained from following link
https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js/tree/master

Use following methods to get the device type

```
device.mobile()
device.tablet()
```

Use below to get the orientation:

```
device.landscape()
device.portrait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only JS you can check window.outerHeight and window.outerWidth.
So, combine different sizes you can define device type.
Also, you can parse navigator.userAgent, which contains name of user browser.

Answer (score 0):

HTML has `user agent` field to send the device information:

**PC**

`mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.3; wow64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/36.0.1985.125 safari/537.36`

**iPhone**

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B176 MicroMessenger/4.3.2`

**Windows Phone**

`UCWEB/2.0 (Windows; U; wds7.10; zh-CN; Nokia 900) U2/1.0.0 UCBrowser/8.6.0.199 U2/1.0.0 Mobile`

1. kernel engine

   IE、Gecko、WebKit、Opera
2. browser type

   IE、Chrome、Firefox、Opera
3. system

   Windows、Mac、Unix
4. mobile device

   iPhone、iPod、Android、Nokia

You could detect like this:

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    //check the device like this
    isChrome = ua.indexOf("chrome") &gt; -1
```